# Azure Portal Directory can't see in appCenter

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-application-insights

I have few directory on my Azure portal which i can access to. Only one I can connect to from appCenter --> Manage --> Azure and the rest of the direction was grey out with text 'You don’t have permission to use this'.

Is there a permission i need to set in azure portal. As far as i know those directory I was set as Owner and can be switched in the portal.

Comment: Which code you use to connect to AppCenter?

Comment: Sorry not the code. Is the setting page in appCenter where i need to configure the export for Application Insight. I can see only one directory but the rest of the directory saying I don't have the permission.